# skipe $_POST in php

Tags: php, post, undefined, skip

i have a php page which i should post some data to it like this:

```
$player=$_POST['player']; $age=$_POST['age']; $data=$_POST['data'];
```

but some times my page posts data and some times it shouldn't, when i dont post data i got Undefined index: error, is there any way to skip $_POST['data'] when no data is posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple `if (isset($_POST['key']))`:

```
$player = isset($_POST['player']) ? $_POST['player'] : '';
$age = isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : '';
$data = isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : '';
```

Or better, but every value to some 'refix':

```
<input name="Data['player']"/>
```

and in php just do:

```
if (isset($_POST['Data'])) {
     $player = $_POST['Data']['player'];
     /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, by why "better, put every value to some 'refix'". Why is this better? Surely you should have used "alternatively". Maybe I'm being pedantic

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Because if prefix is set, than your form is sent and every other values will be set too (unless you are missing html form element, than it will not work).

Comment: $player = $_POST['Data']['player']; i just dont get this data is not related to player so why $_POST['Data']['player']?

Comment: @SinaNouri It's not `data` from your example, it's wrapping key, that holds all information from your form. It's example from Yii framework, where all form data is inside key same as model name. Like you you have contacts form, it will be `$_POST['Contacts']['email']` / `$_POST['Contacts']['content']`...

Answer (score 3):

```
$player = isset($_POST['player'])?$_POST['player']:"";
$age = isset($_POST['age'])?$_POST['age']:"";
$data = isset($_POST['data'])?$_POST['data']:"";
```

The isset first checks if it's defined, if yes, it assigns the variable else it assigns empty string.

Comment: thanks man i didnt know about isset, it is working now haha :D

Comment: if it helped, will you accept my answer? :)

Comment: i just click check sing to accept it but it said not until 12 minutes

Comment: @Rikudou_Senninthere is a 15minute wait before OP can accept any answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['DATA'])){
 $data = $_POST['DATA']
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if(isset($_POST['player'])):
    $player = $_POST['player'];
endif;
```

Comment: This will still show a warning

Comment: That syntax is encouraged for templating: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: because you're checking if against an undefined variable and/or key, you should check that it is set, with `isset` first

Comment: it will still throw the notice... you must use `isset()`

Answer (score -2):

Check if data is posted

```
if(isset($_POST['player']))
$player=$_POST['player'];
}
if(isset($_POST['age']))
$age=$_POST['age'];
}
if(isset($_POST['data']))
$data=$_POST['data'];
}
```

Comment: that's actually only false in CLI :D

Comment: $_POST is always set (in webserver)

Comment: it should work now. please remove downvote